# Converting a max-min normalized array back to its original scale?

Tags: arrays, r

Suppose we have the following array:

```
x=c(2,3,4)
```

I create a variable y in order to convert the array to a common scale using max-min normalization:

```
y=(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
```

I end up with **[0, 0.5, 1]** as my new array.

However, how do I convert the y variable back to the original scale of **2, 3, 4**?

The example I'm working on is more complicated than this, but essentially I need a way of getting my calculated data back to the original scale for the results to make sense. Using this example as a template, would be very appreciative of any advice.

Comment: You need the min and max of the original vector. Then it's a simple transformation. Without these two values, you are stuck.

Comment: Yes, I have these. In the example above, min=2 and max=4. So, how would the transformation work with these two values?

Comment: `(y * abs(diff(range(x)))) + min(x)`.

Comment: That worked. Thank you.